# Sort only a portion of a dictionary in reversed order

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, reverse

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{dist: [lat, long]}
```

dist is the key and the satellite data is actually an array.

I want to sort this in descending order but only a portion of it. The user will input a number specifying the size of the list output to the screen, and I only want to sort in that range from 0 to the size.

How should I do it in the for loop ?
I have:

```
for (n, i) in enumerate(sorted(myDict)):
      if (n >= option):
         break
```

which would sort in ascending order and break when option = the number input by the user. However

```
sorted(myDict, reverse=True)
```

would sort the whole thing in reversed order first , then do the for loop, which is not what I want. Is there a good way to fix this? Obviously I can just create a new array in this for loop, and do another for loop again and sort the new array in descending order

```
array = []
for (n, i) in enumerate(sorted(myDict)):
      if (n >= option):
         break

      array.append(...)

for i in sorted(array, reverse=True):
     print ...
```

Comment: dicts do not have square brackets, they use curly braces and colons {key: value }, what you call a dict there is actually a list

Comment: Oh it was a mistake. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

`heapq.nlargest` is what you are looking for.

```
import heapq

for key in heapq.nlargest(n, myDict):
    print key, myDict[key]
```

Behind the scenes, `heapq.nlargest` builds a heap in O(*N*) time, where *N* is the size of your dict. Accessing the largest (remaining) element takes O(lg *N*) time, so the cumulative cost of getting the *n* largest items is O(*n* lg *N*). As long as *n* is "small enough", this is better than the O(*N* lg *N*) cost of sorting the entire list of keys first.